# JavaScript EventListener not passing event variable to event handler

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to use the event variable to edit the CSS of the element. The error that im getting is saying that event is undefined even tho it should be passed by the event listener.

Thanks for any help

```
function newClick(event){
    event.style.backgroundColor = '#ABAEAB';

    document.addEventListener("keyup" , function(e){           
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        let ele = sel.anchorNode;

        ele.textContent = e.key;
        if(ele.textContent.trim()){
            ele.focus
            setCursorToEnd(ele);    
        }
        ele.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';   
        ele.parentElement.setAttribute("class" , "old");   
    });
}

function SetNewBranch(){
    let li_NewSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("new");

    for(let i = 0; i < li_NewSpan.length; i++){        
        if(li_NewSpan[i].getAttribute("EventListener") == 'false' && li_NewSpan[i].getAttribute("class") == "new"){          
            li_NewSpan[i].addEventListener("click" , newClick , false);            
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: with the Click event on the element

Comment: `event` is the click event, not the element that was clicked.  For that you want [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `keyup` event inside a click handler which will add new listener function everytime a click happens which is not right!
Take `keyup` event handler to its own function and call it **once** inside `SetNewBranch` or whereever you need. see example below.
Also, to get the element, you can use `event.target`

```js
function attachKeyUpEvent() {
document.addEventListener("keyup" , function(e){           
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        let ele = sel.anchorNode;

        ele.textContent = e.key;
        if(ele.textContent.trim()){
            ele.focus
//            setCursorToEnd(ele);    
        }
        ele.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';   
        ele.parentElement.setAttribute("class" , "old");   
   });
}
    
function newClick(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ABAEAB';
}

function SetNewBranch(){
    let li_NewSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("new");

    for(let i = 0; i < li_NewSpan.length; i++){        
        if(!li_NewSpan[i].getAttribute("EventListener") && li_NewSpan[i].getAttribute("class") == "new"){          
            li_NewSpan[i].addEventListener("click" , newClick , false);            
        }
    }
   attachKeyUpEvent();
}

SetNewBranch();
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="new"> one </li>
<li class="new"> two </li>
<li class="new"> three </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the keyup event should one run when the click event has ran once and then after one use per element, the eventlisteners should be removed and the class = 'old'